# itoa conversion in C#

Tags: c#

It was an interview question asked to me - write `itoa` conversion without using any builtin functions.

The following is the algorithm I am using. But `('0' + n % 10);` is throwing an error:

> cannot convert string to int

```
private static string itoa(int n)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    char c;

    bool sign = n > 0 ? true : false;
    while (true)
    {
        result = result + ('0' + n % 10);  //'0' 
        n = n / 10;
        if(n <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }               
    }

    if(sign)
    {
        result =  result + '-';
    }

    return  strReverse(result);
}
```

Comment: Usually we just use `ToString()` in C#

Comment: This `('0' + n % 10)` should probably be just `(n % 10)`. But consider minitech`s comment.

Comment: Also `result = "-" + result;` should probably be `result = result + "-";`, as you're doing reverse at the end.

Comment: i used '0'as ASCII 48 to convert int to char, standard way.

Comment: It was an interview question asked to me.

Comment: This doesn't throw anything, but it does produce incorrect results. `'0' + n % 10` results in an `int`, which you then concatenate to a string, resulting in an implicit `ToString`, not a cast to char. e.g. `'0' + 1`  is `49`, which as a string is `"49"`, not `"1"`.

Comment: @user2480288 The answer to that interview question is, "Nobody hires C# developers to rewrite built-in functionality; it's a waste of time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @minitech commented, we usually just use `ToString()` to do that in C#. If you really want to write the algorithm on your own, the following is an implementation:

```
public static partial class TestClass {
    public static String itoa(int n, int radix) {
        if(0==n)
            return "0";

        var index=10;
        var buffer=new char[1+index];
        var xlat="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for(int r=Math.Abs(n), q; r>0; r=q) {
            q=Math.DivRem(r, radix, out r);
            buffer[index-=1]=xlat[r];
        }

        if(n<0) {
            buffer[index-=1]='-';
        }

        return new String(buffer, index, buffer.Length-index);
    }

    public static void TestMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", itoa(-0x12345678, 16));
    }
}
```

It works only for `int`. The range `int` is `-2147483648 to 2147483647`, the length in the string representation would be max to 11.

For the signature of `itoa` in C is `char * itoa(int n, char * buffer, int radix);`, but we don't need to pass the buffer in C#, we can allocate it locally.

The approach that add '0' to the remainder may not work when the radix is greater than `10`; if I recall correctly, `itoa` in C supports up to 36 based numbers, as this implementation is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unclear why you'd want to do this; just call [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.ToString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your integer.  You can specify whatever formatting you need with the various overloads.

Comment: I want to write a itoa algorithm without using any builtin functions

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @crashmstr somtimes when someone asks you if they should use a old shoe or a glass bottle to pound in a nail, [you need to tell them to get a hammer](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx)!

Comment: @crashmstr When I first answered the question, no explanation was given as to why the poster was trying to do their own itoa, so I felt that he simply was new to C# and didn't know about the built in function.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm not saying anything about the *content* with my comment, what I'm saying is that it probably should have been a *comment* instead of an *answer*. As an example, see some of the other comments...

Answer (score 0):

`('0' + n % 10)` results in an `int` value, so you should cast it back to `char`. There are also several other issues with your code, like adding `-` sign on the wrong side, working with negative values, etc.

My version:

```
static string itoa(int n)
{
    char[] result = new char[11]; // 11 = "-2147483648".Length
    int index = result.Length;
    bool sign = n < 0;

    do
    {
        int digit = n % 10;
        if(sign)
        {
            digit = -digit;
        }
        result[--index] = (char)('0' + digit);
        n /= 10;
    }
    while(n != 0);

    if(sign)
    {
        result[--index] = '-';
    }

    return new string(result, index, result.Length - index);
}
```